# IndexError: list index out of range (on an array)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("NOTE: Parcels can only be smaller than 100x100x100cm (WxLxH) and weight less than 20kg")
parcelAmount = int(input("How many parcels are you sending?: "))
for i in range(parcelAmount):
      parcelWidth.append(input("Please enter the width of the parcel " + str(i + 1) + ": "))
      parcelLength.append(input("Please enter the length of the parcel " + str(i + 1) + ": "))
      parcelHeight.append(input("Please enter the height of the parcel " + str(i + 1) + ": "))
      parcelWeight.append(input("please enter the weight of the parcel " + str(i + 1) + ": "))
      i = i + 1
if float(parcelWidth[i]) or float(parcelLength[i]) or float(parcelHeight[i]) > int(100) or float(parcelWeight[i]) > int(20):
    parcelRej = parcelRej + 1
parcelAcc = parcelAmount - parcelRej
if float(parcelWeight[i]) > 1 and float(parcelWeight[i]) < 5:
    parcelPrice[i] = 10
if float(parcelWeight[i]) > 5:
    parcelPrice[i] = parcelWeight[i] - 5 + 10   
print("There are " + str(parcelRej) + " parcels rejected")
print("There are " + str(parcelAcc) + " parcels accepted")
print("It will cost $" + str(sum(parcelPrice)) + " To ship the parcel")
```

This code finds the price to send parcels. I keep getting "IndexError: list index out of range" for all of the if statements and I dont know why please help me. Thanks in Advance :).

This is the full code but stack overflow says it is too much code and not enough details so I will just add this paragraph to add space so I can add the full code like you guys asked. So how are you guys doing? where you guys from? How old are you guys? Why is it still too little text and too much code... UGH when will this be over?

Comment: Well usually that is (dums) because **the index is out of range**. Do you know for sure the value of `i` is between `0` (inclusive) and `len(pracelLength)` (exclusive).

Comment: can u show your full code along with iterations(for-loop,while loop).

Comment: atleast can u mention length of parcelWidth,parcelLength,parcelHeight,parcelWeight..??

Comment: Yes it is between 0 and len(parcelLength) I just couldn't post the whole code because it said it was too much code and not enough description

Comment: I added the full code apart from where I declared the arrays and variables hope that helps @shiva

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need a deeper understanding of what an array is. Array has its size, so you need to make sure that you are not exceeding it. Take your `parcelWidth[i]`. Index out of range error happens when `i` has a higher value than size of `parcelWidth` -1 (that is because first element of an array is indexed as 0).

Example:

```
>>> parcelWidth = [1,2,3,4]
>>> i = 0
>>> parcelWidth[i]
1
>>> i = 3
>>> parcelWidth[i]
4
>>> i = 4
>>> parcelWidth[i]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Do you get the concept now? You can't access array element that doesn't exist.

To quickly check the length of an array you can use len(), like that:

```
>>> len(parcelWidth)
4
```

To avoid your error don't access elements that don't exist. Probably you should control how high your `i` goes and check if all arrays have enough elements.

Answer (score 0):

mr.Lewys the problem in your code is u mentioned (i=i+1) in for loop. For loop will auto increment the i till it's last index no need to increment(i) in for loop but if u like to write code using while loop u have to increment i. The code is

```
print("NOTE: Parcels can only be smaller than 100x100x100cm (WxLxH) 
and weight less than 20kg")
parcelAmount = int(input("How many parcels are you sending?: "))
#parcelWidth=[]
#parcelLength=[]
#parcelHeight=[]
#parcelWeight=[]
#parcelRej=0
#for i in range(parcelAmount):
    parcelWidth.append(input("Please enter the width of the parcel " + 
    str(i + 1) + ": "))
    parcelLength.append(input("Please enter the length of the parcel " 
    + str(i + 1) + ": "))
    parcelHeight.append(input("Please enter the height of the parcel " 
    + str(i + 1) + ": "))
    parcelWeight.append(input("please enter the weight of the parcel " 
    + str(i + 1) + ": "))
    # i = i + 1
if float(parcelWidth[i]) or float(parcelLength[i]) or float(parcelHeight[i]) > 100 or float(parcelWeight[i]) > 20:
    parcelRej = parcelRej + 1
parcelAcc = parcelAmount - parcelRej
if float(parcelWeight[i]) > 1 and float(parcelWeight[i]) < 5:
    parcelPrice[i] = 10
if float(parcelWeight[i]) > 5:
    parcelPrice[i] = parcelWeight[i] - 5 + 10
print("There are " + str(parcelRej) + " parcels rejected")
print("There are " + str(parcelAcc) + " parcels accepted")
print("It will cost $" + str(sum(parcelPrice)) + " To ship the parcel")
```

and i am getting error as parcelPrice is not defined because idk the values of that.

Hope this is useful for u..